# Slurm incorrectly padding unicode

Tags: slurm

When submitting jobs with sbatch, I often like to put unicode characters in my job names. However, when this happens, it seems like sbatch things each unicode character is two characters long, even though in my Terminal it's displayed as one character. This causes the formatting to look strange:

[image]

Is there any way to make the character padding work better (without having to put the job name at the end of the line)? This is the squeue command that causes the issue:

```
squeue --user $USER --format '%10j %18i ...'
```

Comment: I decided to just write a python script to parse the output, which works much better than slurm's way of doing it anyway, allowing for e.g. variable spacing between columns based on content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `column` command with the `-t` argument that will take care of unicode character alignment and make column widths dynamic:

```
$ squeue  --me --format "%30j %18i"
NAME                           JOBID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx                 10797040
P6                             10797007
δ0.2_λ0.25                   10797003
$ squeue  --me --format "%30j %18i" | column -t
NAME            JOBID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx  10797040
P6              10797007
δ0.2_λ0.25      10797003
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! It turns out using my Python script allows for some more usage features (e.g. showing the total # of CPUs used on each partition), but this is very useful for those times I'm not parsing the output